# Base change of regular schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, neron-models, regular-rings

Let $R$ be a complete DVR with fraction field $K$, $X$ be a regular scheme flat over $R$. Let $L$ be a finite field extension of $K$ and $Q$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $L$. Denote by $Y:=X \times_R Q$ the base change of $X$. Is $Y$ a regular scheme? If not true in general, is there any additional assumption on $R$ for which this holds true?

PS. One can assume that the characteristic of $K$ is zero.

Comment: Check out formally smooth and/or geometrically regular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Take $R=\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $X$ to be the affine scheme defined by $xy=p$.  This is regular, but its base change to $\mathbb{Z}_p[\sqrt{p}]$ is not.

If $X$ is smooth over $R$, then $Y$ is smooth over $Q$ (and therefore regular in many useful situations).  This is of course a much stronger assumption.

Comment: And if you want an equal-characteristic example, take $R=\mathbf C[[t]]$ and $X$ be the closed subscheme of $\mathbf A^2_R$ defined by $xy=t$; it is regular, but its base change to $\mathbf C[[t^{1/2}]]$ is not.